Total permutations for n-married couples

Let A(n) denote the number of ways of seating n-married couples, around a circle, such that men and women sit alternately, and no husband sits next to his wife. Then Compute A(5):

I tried applying PIE (Principle of inclusion-exclusion):
I defined an event E(i) denoting if i-th cooples sat together.
Total casees of alternate arrangement: 5! × 4!
Now required cases:
Total cases - P(E(1) U E(2) U E(3) .... E(5))
But computing intersections of E(i) were getting too complex to deal with.
Is there any possible way to get ahead with this and handling cases easily?
Please do share if you have a different method, because this doesn't seems as an appropriate method.
Can we also compute cases for n-married couples, where there is no bound for alternative sitting? I tried it  with inclusion- exclusion.
The question's IInd part asked the remainder of total cases when divided by 5. The answer was 3 and i was getting 2.
Please help! Thanks :)

https://oeis.org/A094047

Is that link supposed to help? Please elaborate.

The link gives $312$ as the answer for the case $n=5$, and gives a summation-based formula for the general case.

Yes 312 is the answer, could you please elaborate?

First I calculated the total number of ways men and women can sit alternatively (couple or not) : That is 4!x5!
Then I calculated the cases in which men and women are seated alternatively as couples : 4!x2
Finally, I subtracted the second part from the first to get 2832 as my answer.
(remainder=2)

But the answer to the 1st paet is 312, when there is no bound for sitting then remainder is given 2
